# JavaScript: after append script is not working

Tags: javascript, css

I have script which is creating number of new inputs according to inserted value to input.

New inputs are extended with another script but this script is not working.

This script is working when appended html code is not in js but in index.html. Then this script works fine but the first script is not launched.

**CODE:**

```js
$(function () { 
            
    $(".main-input1").on("change", function () {
        $(".activityType1.active").removeClass("active");
        var subList = $(".activityType1." + $(this).val());
        if (subList.length) {
            subList.addClass("active");
        }
    });
});

    const button = document.querySelector('button');
    const input = document.getElementById('NumberOfNights');
    const wrapper = document.querySelector('div.wrapper-activity');

    function generateItems(numOfItems) {
        let html = "";
        wrapper.innerHTML = "";
    
        for(i = 1; i <= numOfItems; i++) {
        html += `
        <style>
         .activityType1 {
            display: none;
        }
        .activityType1.active {
            display: inline-block;
        }
        </style>
        <section class="activity-wrapper">
        <label for="activity">Activity ${i}</label>
        <div class="select-style">
            <select id="activity" style="width: 300px;" name="activity" class='main-input1'>
                <option value='none' disabled selected>--</option>
                <option value='Hiking'>Hiking</option>
                <option value='Biking'>Biking</option>
                <option value='Tasting'>Tasting</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class='activityType1 Hiking activity-wrapper'>
        <div class="bottom-row">
            <label class="hiking-activity">
                <input type="radio" name="hiking-activity" value="National park Pieniny">
                <img src="../assets/img/3.jpg">
            </label>

            <label class="hiking-activity">
                <input type="radio" name="hiking-activity" value="National park Slovak paradise">
                <img src="../assets/img/4.jpg">
            </label>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class='activityType1 Biking activity-wrapper'>
        <div class="top-row">
            <label class="biking-activity">
                <input type="radio" name="biking-activity" value="National park High Tatras">
                <img src="../assets/img/5.jpg">
            </label>

            <label class="biking-activity">
                <input type="radio" name="biking-activity" value="National park Pieniny">
                <img src="../assets/img/6.jpg">
            </label>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class='activityType1 Tasting activity-wrapper'>
        <div class="top-row">
            <label class="tasting-activity">
                <input type="radio" name="tasting-activity" value="Beer tasting">
                <img src="../assets/img/10.jpg">
            </label>

            <label class="tasting-activity">
                <input type="radio" name="tasting-activity" value="Whisky tour">
                <img src="../assets/img/11.jpg">
            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="bottom-row">
            <label class="tasting-activity">
                <input type="radio" name="tasting-activity" value="Tokaj wine tour">
                <img src="../assets/img/12.jpg">
            </label>
        </div>
    </section>
        `;
        };
        return html;
    };


    button.addEventListener('click',() => {
        const n = parseInt(input.value);
        if (n) {
            wrapper.innerHTML = generateItems(n);
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="NumberOfNights" placeholder="--" type="number" name="nights" max="5">
<button type="button">Continue</button>
<div class="wrapper-activity"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to `$(document).on('change', '.main-input1', function () {` this way your first script can be launched on the appended code.

```js
$(function () { 
    $(document).on('change', '.main-input1', function () {
        $(".activityType1.active").removeClass("active");
        var subList = $(".activityType1." + $(this).val());
        if (subList.length) {
            subList.addClass("active");
        }
    });
});

    const button = document.querySelector('button');
    const input = document.getElementById('NumberOfNights');
    const wrapper = document.querySelector('div.wrapper-activity');

    function generateItems(numOfItems) {
        let html = "";
        wrapper.innerHTML = "";
    
        for(i = 1; i <= numOfItems; i++) {
        html += `
        <style>
         .activityType1 {
            display: none;
        }
        .activityType1.active {
            display: inline-block;
        }
        </style>
        <section class="activity-wrapper">
        <label for="activity">Activity ${i}</label>
        <div class="select-style">
            <select id="activity" style="width: 300px;" name="activity" class='main-input1'>
                <option value='none' disabled selected>--</option>
                <option value='Hiking'>Hiking</option>
                <option value='Biking'>Biking</option>
                <option value='Tasting'>Tasting</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class='activityType1 Hiking activity-wrapper'>
        <div class="bottom-row">
            <label class="hiking-activity">
                <input type="radio" name="hiking-activity" value="National park Pieniny">
                <img src="../assets/img/3.jpg">
            </label>

            <label class="hiking-activity">
                <input type="radio" name="hiking-activity" value="National park Slovak paradise">
                <img src="../assets/img/4.jpg">
            </label>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class='activityType1 Biking activity-wrapper'>
        <div class="top-row">
            <label class="biking-activity">
                <input type="radio" name="biking-activity" value="National park High Tatras">
                <img src="../assets/img/5.jpg">
            </label>

            <label class="biking-activity">
                <input type="radio" name="biking-activity" value="National park Pieniny">
                <img src="../assets/img/6.jpg">
            </label>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class='activityType1 Tasting activity-wrapper'>
        <div class="top-row">
            <label class="tasting-activity">
                <input type="radio" name="tasting-activity" value="Beer tasting">
                <img src="../assets/img/10.jpg">
            </label>

            <label class="tasting-activity">
                <input type="radio" name="tasting-activity" value="Whisky tour">
                <img src="../assets/img/11.jpg">
            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="bottom-row">
            <label class="tasting-activity">
                <input type="radio" name="tasting-activity" value="Tokaj wine tour">
                <img src="../assets/img/12.jpg">
            </label>
        </div>
    </section>
        `;
        };
        return html;
    };


    button.addEventListener('click',() => {
        const n = parseInt(input.value);
        if (n) {
            wrapper.innerHTML = generateItems(n);
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="NumberOfNights" placeholder="--" type="number" name="nights" max="5">
<button type="button">Continue</button>
<div class="wrapper-activity"></div>
```